# Jquery - Set live('hover') and bind('contextmenu') on the same .class?

Tags: jquery

it is possible to bind Live('hover') and bind('contextmenu') on the same .class?

This code dont work

```
$('.too').bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#ttt').append('click ' + this.id + '<br />');
});

$('.too').live('hover', function(event) {
    $('#ttt').append('click ' + this.id + '<br />');
}
});
```

here is a working example
http://jsfiddle.net/CD5tX/15/

Thanks in Advance
Peter

Comment: may I ask what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error (an extra `}` character), it seems to work when that is fixed.

see http://jsfiddle.net/CD5tX/17/

Answer (score 0):

may I ask what you are trying to do?

Cause on the looks of it you are binding a custom event which is named `contextmenu`. If you try to trigger it (on click for example) it will work.

[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/CD5tX/16/),

```
$('.too').bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#ttt').append('click ' + this.id + '<br />');
}).click(function(){
    $(this).trigger("contextmenu");
});
```